# How to push datasets dynamically for chart.js (bar chart)?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Im using chartjs (bar chart) to display some data.
Im trying to dynamically add data to **datasets** array but its not working.

for example, lets say I have 2 objects in datasets array, and I dynamically  creating this object and trying to push him into datasets (from Chrome console)
after the page loaded and chart is already up.

```
var e = {
                fillColor : "#efefef",
                strokeColor : "#efefef",
                highlightFill: "#efefef",
                highlightStroke: "#efefef",
                data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
            }
```

and then

```
barChartData.datasets.push(e)
```

I also tried to do `window.myBar.update()`
but again nothing happend.

Do you know this issue? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think you can use addData to add a series - it's for adding points / bars to existing series.

However you can insert your new series directly into the chart object. With the chart object and new dataset like so

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data);

var myNewDataset = {
    label: "My Second dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(187,205,151,0.5)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(187,205,151,0.8)",
    highlightFill: "rgba(187,205,151,0.75)",
    highlightStroke: "rgba(187,205,151,1)",
    data: [48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90, 28]
}
```

the code to insert a new dataset would be

```
var bars = []
myNewDataset.data.forEach(function (value, i) {
    bars.push(new myBarChart.BarClass({
        value: value,
        label: myBarChart.datasets[0].bars[i].label,
        x: myBarChart.scale.calculateBarX(myBarChart.datasets.length + 1, myBarChart.datasets.length, i),
        y: myBarChart.scale.endPoint,
        width: myBarChart.scale.calculateBarWidth(myBarChart.datasets.length + 1),
        base: myBarChart.scale.endPoint,
        strokeColor: myNewDataset.strokeColor,
        fillColor: myNewDataset.fillColor
    }))
})

myBarChart.datasets.push({
    bars: bars
})

myBarChart.update();
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/pvak6rkx/ (inserts the new dataset after 3 seconds)

Comment: tnx! its working.
Can I remove data in a similar way?

Comment: Yep, I just tried a `myBarChart.datasets.pop();` and it worked

Comment: Youre the best. and if I wanna remove spesific dataset?

Comment: just use Array.splice to kick out the dataset you don't want

Answer (score 15):

In version 2.x, you can add (or remove) data to the chart directly and then call `update()`, e.g.

```
barChart.data.datasets.push({
  label: 'label2',
  backgroundColor: '#ff0000',
  data: [1,2,3]
});
barChart.update();
```

Here's a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/flivni/Lcnj1e5x/).

Answer (score 0):

Your missing the `data` key from your chart instance i.e. `barChartData.data.datasets.push(e);`
No need for any methods.  The js chart object `data.datasets` key accepts an array of objects. Therefore in your case use :

```
var e = {
         fillColor : "#efefef",
         strokeColor : "#efefef",
         highlightFill: "#efefef",
         highlightStroke: "#efefef",
         data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
            }
barChartData.data.datasets[] = e; // this will append additional data to your chart
barChartData.update();
```

Just make sure that `barChartData` is an instance of your js chart.

Answer (score 0):

In 3th version you need to use update with reset mode.

```
        chart.update('reset');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).